# Compute $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\left(\frac1x\right)^n$ where $x>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to show analytic solution to

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1n\left(\frac1x\right)^n$$

where $x>1$?

Recently in a Fourier class we have found the sums by evaluating at a specific value and using the equality defined by the FS, but none of the coefficients so far have created anything like $(1/x)^n$. I wolframmed the problem an it gave me a specific value, but I was wondering how it got that value, and if you have to use a Fourier Series what function is used to find the unique coefficients.

Comment: Note that this is a power series in $1/x$. Do you recognize $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}n$? Hint: what do you get when you differentiate this power series?

Comment: Hint: Use the variable $t=1/x$ and differentiate with respect to $t$. The result is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n-1}=\frac1{1-t},$$ if $|t|<1$, hence...

Comment: @hbp How does that even help the OP?

Comment: See [Mercator series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Comment: I like the term "wolframmed"! I suppose "wolframalphaed" would be too long... :)

Comment: I always say "using wolfy".

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = 1/x$ and note that $0 < z < 1$ and note that
$$
f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}
     < \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k
     = \frac{1}{1-z}-1,
$$
so the function is well-defined, since the sum converges. Differentiate in the radius of convergence to get
$$
f'(z)
  = \sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{k-1} 
  = \sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k
  = \frac{1}{1-z}.
$$

Thus, your sum should be
$$
f(z)
 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}
 = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1-z} + \text{const}
 = \text{const} - \ln(1-z)
$$

**UPDATE**
To determine the constant, note that $f(0) = 0$, and since $\ln(1-z) = 0$ at $z=0$, the constant is zero as well. In other words,
$$
f(z) = -\ln(1-z) = \ln \left( \frac{1}{1-z} \right)
$$

Comment: The constant has to be $0$, because when $x = 0$, the left-hand side is $0$.

Comment: @Bungo updated, thanks

Comment: @gt6989b: Probably also worth mentioning that your $x$ is the OP's $1/x$...

Comment: @Bungo i was hoping he would figure it out by himself... but will write this explicitly

Comment: @gt6989b: Probably a reasonable assumption, but mentioning it explicitly highlights the subtle detail that we are plugging in $z=0$ (which for the OP is $x=\infty$) to evaluate the constant (easily fixed by plugging in some other $z > 0$).

Comment: @Bungo not worth thr trouble, he can take $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \ln(1-x) = 0$$